# CUDA: Reasons for using preprocessing variables to specify the problem size

Tags: matlab, cuda, preprocessor

I'm coding CUDA in Matlab mex-Files. When you look at CUDA examples on the internet or even manuals from nvidia, you often see the use of preprocessing variables to specify the problem size, e.g. the vector length for a vector addition or something like this. I coded my program also like this: Preprocessing Variables for specifying the problem size. And I have to admit it: I like it since you can access those everywhere in your code, e.g. as limits in a loop or something like this, without having to explicitly pass them via argument to the function.

But I ran into the following problem: I wanted to bench the program for several different problem sizes and thus I need to compile the code everytime again by passing the preprocessing-variable to the compiler. It's not a problem, I already coded the benchmark and it works. But I just wonder afterwards now, why I chose this version and did not simply specify it by a user input on runtime. And thus I'm looking for reasons one might want to use preprocessing variables instead of simply passing the problem size to the program.

Thanks!

Comment: It's quite possible that the CUDA C compiler needs to know the sizes at compile time, so at best you could get away with static constants.

Comment: Does the compiler need to know it at runtime when declaring a constant array in my code with a certain size (the size is the problem size)?

Comment: Hmmm... the compiler isn't involved anymore at runtime. Constant arrays are handled by the compiler at compile time. For variable-length arrays the compiler generates code that will allocate the memory at runtime. But for the CUDA stuff it's entirely possible that it's impossible to arrange for the thread geometry dynamically, so those sizes must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that in general the problem size will be intimately linked to the GPU architecture, e.g. number of threads per block, number of blocks, amount of shared memory per thread, number of registers per thread, etc. In general these numbers are all carefully hand tuned to get the maximum usage of available resources and you can't easily change the problem size dynamically while still maintaining optimum performance.

Comment: Yeah you can't keep up the best performance, that's probably true in general, but for a vector addition or matrix addition, I think you don't want to figure out the best problem size for all your done optimizations: Rather you'd like to try to optimize your code to the max and than still make the problem size somehow at least a bit variable, so that you can use the code not only for ONE fix scenario, but for general usage!?

Comment: It may not be optimal but you can programmatically query the device for it's capabilities and make it calculate approximate good values to use in your kernel launches. If you are doing something that you want to distribute and will run on different machines that's something you should do.

Answer (score 4):

When you compile-in problem-size constants in the kernel, then the compiler can make certain classes of optimizations that it can't if the sizes are only known at runtime.   Full loop unrolling is an obvious example.

In other cases, for instance shared memory array sizes, it is a lot clearer if the sizes are compiled-in; otherwise you have to pass in the total shared memory size at kernel launch time and break that memory up into the number of shared arrays you need.  That works fine, but the code is much clearer if you can just have static declarations, for which you need the compile-time sizes.